# Adding seconds to string date in bash

Tags: linux, bash, date

I have a variable string date like this

```
#!/bin/bash
timeString="Mar 15 09:27:26"
```

I want to add 10 second to this variable and I do not know how.
It might be a duplicate post, but I did not had the inspiration to find a simple answer.

Comment: Convert to seconds, add 10, convert back to date string.

Comment: *"but I did not had the inspiration to find a simple answer..."* - Lol... I guess that means you want the folks on Stack Overflow to find a duplicate for you or write it for you. This should help you: [bash convert string to date and add seconds](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=bash+convert+string+to+date+and+add+seconds). What surprises me is, someone upvoted the question. It is a testament to the low standards on the site...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert to seconds, add 10, convert back to date string:

```
date +"%a %d %H:%M:%S" --date=@$(($(date +%s --date="Mar 15 09:27:26") + 10))
```

Uses `$((...))` arithmetic substitution and `$(...)` command substitution of bash, and format converting functions of GNU date. (Note: On Mac, `date` has a different format)